# What is the time complexity of this delete function?

Tags: python, time, complexity-theory

I am trying to find the time complexity for this function in Python but I don't really understand how to account for the if/else statement. I have only ever seen for loops. Also, this is a recursive function and I am not sure if that affects the big oh notation.

```
def delete(root,data):
    if root is None:                              O(1)
        return node
    if data < root.data:                        O(1)
        root.left = delete(root.left, data)  
    elif data > root.data:                        O(1)
        root.right = delete(root.right,data)
    else:                                         O(n)

        if root.left == None:                   O(n)
            temp = root.right
            self = None
        return temp
        elif root.right == None:                  O(n)
            temp = root.left
            self = None
        return temp
        else:                                     O(n)
            temp = minval(node.right)
            root.data = temp.data
            root.right = delete(root.right,temp.data)
```

I wrote on the side of my code what I think the time complexity of each statement is. I believe this function has a time complexity of O(n^2). Please let me know if I am wrong!

Comment: You don't need to worry about the `if` statements. All that matters is how many times the code repeats.

Comment: `return temp` needs to be indented or you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: What's the point of `self = None`? You never use the variable `self` anywhere.

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave the class definition of the root object.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is O(log n).

All the `if` statements are O(1). The only repetition comes from the recursive calls. The recursion operates on half the tree (either `root.left` or `root.right`), so each iteration divides the size of the problem in half on average.